# Validating jsp using XSD

Tags: jsp, parsing, optimization, xsd

A JSP page contains multiple components like button , li. where button tag having attributes like id, class, type, onclick. where my requirement is to maintain a common xsd file and validate the JSP files wheather the li tag having the defined attributes(defined in XSD). button having the defined attributes.This is not a data validation, this is to validate the JSP page to optimize the code. kindly suggest me how and where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Tagsoup for JSP parsing , getting tag names, attributes from the JSP.